# Is there any way to customize an iOS keyboard to only show the microphone button?

Tags: ios, keyboard, microphone

I've been ask if it is possible to create a custom iOS keyboard with nothing in it but the microphone button (lower left on the standard text keyboard) and still get the microphone functionality. Mainly this would be for a voice only entry (the resulting text would be processed elsewhere).

Yes, it's an oddball question...